# Point around a square with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, plot

I was kindly given the code below by AtomicRobot on stackoverflow.

```
var x,y;

// amount of chairs
var totalChairs = 12;
// square size
var squareSize = 200;
var chairSize = 60;

// issues with 3,5,7,8,9,10,11

for(var i=0; i<totalChairs; i++){

    var angle = 2*Math.PI * i/totalChairs;

    if (angle > Math.PI/4 && angle <= Math.PI* 3/4){
        x = (squareSize/2) / Math.tan(angle);
        y = -squareSize/2 - chairSize/2;
    } else if (angle > Math.PI* 3/4 && angle <= Math.PI* 5/4){
        x = -squareSize/2 - chairSize/2;
        y = (squareSize/2) * Math.tan(angle);
    } else if (angle > Math.PI* 5/4 && angle <= Math.PI* 7/4){
        x = -(squareSize/2) / Math.tan(angle);
        y = -squareSize/2 + squareSize + chairSize/2;
    } else {
        x = -squareSize/2 + squareSize + chairSize/2;
        y = -(squareSize/2) * Math.tan(angle);
    }

    x -= Math.round(chairSize/2) - squareSize/2;
    y -= Math.round(chairSize/2) - squareSize/2;

    $("#square").append("<div class='chair' style='left:"+x+"px;top:"+y+"px;'></div>");
}
```

which is to plot chairs around a table with javascript it works great for the following amount of chairs 1,2,4,6,12 the distances are plotted equally.

But with the following amount of chairs 3,5,7,8,9,10,11 the seems to be of by the chair width.

Is their anyone that can let me know why this might be occurring maths isn't my strong point and would really appreciate some help with this, you can see a example here with 8 chairs.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ld769/4/

Thanks

Ive been making progress with this completely change how i am doing it now actually understand whats going on with this one and can expand the table to suit still having issue with the remander to for certain people numbers????

```
       var x,y;

// amount of chairs
var totalChairs = 18;
var chairSize = 60;
// square size
var squareSize = Math.round(totalChairs/4) * chairSize;

//alert("squareSize: " + squareSize);
// issues with 5,9,13,17,21
// works with 1,2,4,6,12
var remainder = Math.round(totalChairs/4);

var s1 = 0;
var s2 = 0;
var s3 = 0;
var s4 = 0;

for(var i=0; i<totalChairs; i++){

    var iter = i;  
    if(iter+1 <= remainder){

         var s1i = s1++;
         console.log("s1i: " + s1i);

         x = s1i * chairSize;
         y = -chairSize;
         newr = remainder*2;

    } else if(iter+1 <= newr){
         var s2i = s2++;
         console.log("s2i: " + s2i);
         y = s2i * chairSize;
         x= squareSize;
         newe = remainder*3;

    } else if(iter+1 <= newe){

         var s3i = s3++;
         console.log("s3i: " + s3i);
         x =  - s3i * chairSize  + squareSize - chairSize;
         y = squareSize;

    }else{
         var s4i = s4++;
         console.log("s4i: " + s4i);
         y = - s4i * chairSize + squareSize - chairSize;
         x= -chairSize;

     }         

    $("#square").css({"width":(squareSize) + "px","height":(squareSize) + "px"});
    $("#square").append("<div class='chair' style='left:"+Math.round(x)+"px;top:"+Math.round(y)+"px;'><p>"+i+"<br/>x"+x+",y"+y+"</p></div>");
    $(".chair").css({"width":(chairSize) + "px","height":(chairSize) + "px"});
}
```

​

​
can see the jsfiddle version here
http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/Ld769/19/

Comment: Do you require that the table and the chairs don't overlap? Why the table has to be squared?

Comment: hi Raffaele the table has to be square as we are doing this for a variety of shapes like circle here http://jsfiddle.net/jE26S/12/ but square is proving tricky yes the requirement would be that the table and chairs dont overlap thanks;)

Comment: Yes, a circular table would be the correct choice here. If you want to use a squared one, you must tell something more about the placement. For example, if chairs must *touch* the table or if the distance between two consecutive chairs centers must be constant

Comment: @user1503606: If you have 11 chairs, how would you distribute them around a table?

Comment: Hi Amberlamps yes this is the problem im finding with 11 9 etc i am thinking they should be equal distances the same as if their was 12 chairs but with one missing. Raffaele the chairs must just touch the outer edge of the table and the distance across one side should be equal as Amberlamps pointed out tho this is tricky for 11 9 etc

Comment: @user1503606: There is no trivial math functions (if there is ever any) that can decide where and when to leave out chairs to not screw up the layout.

Comment: thanks Amberlamps im thinking of just doing something like this as a solution http://jsfiddle.net/Ld769/7/

Comment: i'd figure how many need to fit on one of the 4 sides. 4*2 = 8, not sufficient, 4*3 = 12 OK!, that means 3 sides get three and one gets 2. that means the minimum width and height must be the same as the most packed side (so that the seated fit comfortably)

Answer (score 0):

i'd figure how many need to fit on one of the 4 sides. 4*2 = 8, not sufficient, 4*3 = 12 OK!, that means 3 sides get three and one gets 2. that means the minimum width and height must be the same as the most packed side (so that the seated fit comfortably)

if you want to have them evenly separated? Just figure out the number of chairs, say it's 11, divide into 360 to figure your angle of separation then project that onto the square

Comment: The current code appears to be doing as you suggest for the even division of the circle, but the projection is where it is going wrong. Dividing into the number of sides seems like a more useful pursuit.